# JQuery UI autocomplete. Issues / not enough results

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm currently implementing a search engine with JQuery UI autocomplete.
The records are stored in a mysql db.
It returns results, but not enough.
If I execute a search with `LIKE %"abdo"%` in phpmyadmin, I get 6 results; In the present case, with Jquery and the db call script, I don't even get one.
Sometimes, it suggests the word, but only after 3 or 4 characters. It's surprising, because I put MinLength to 0 in the settings.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        //autocomplete
        $(".auto").autocomplete({
            source: "autocomplate.php",
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0
        });

    });
</script>
```

And part of the **autocomplate.php**:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT word_fr FROM words_medina WHERE word_fr LIKE :term');
$stmt->execute(array('term' => '%' . $_GET['term'] . '%'));

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $return_arr[] =  $row['word_fr'];
}
```

Has anyboday any idea? I would appreciate your kind support. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking for "acide" in the db, there are 16 matches. Again, not a single one with Jquery UI and the autocomplate query.

Comment: Can you edit and supply an example of the response from `autocomplate.php?term=aci` or the like. Suspect the lack of JSON encoding might also play a part in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest using PHP like:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT word_fr FROM words_medina WHERE word_fr LIKE :term');
$stmt->execute(array('term' => '%' . $_GET['term'] . '%'));
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $return_arr[] =  $row['word_fr'];
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

See more: [Returning JSON from a PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)

You should see results like:

```
[
  "string 1",
  "string 2",
  "string 3"
]
```

If you're  not, then something else is an issue in your Query or PHP.